# Failed to connect to hadoop hdfs on Mac OS

Tags: hadoop

I have installed hadoop on a MacOS system but failed to connect to hdfs. Below is the configuration file:

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>  
<property>
     <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
     <value>/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/hdfs/tmp</value>
     <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>fs.default.name</name>                                     
     <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>                             
  </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>localhost:9010</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I run `/usr/local/opt/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh;/usr/local/opt/hadoop/sbin/start-yarn.sh` to start hadoop. After start it, I got below error. Is there anything I did wrong?

```
$ hadoop fs -ls
17/05/03 17:00:29 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: End of File Exception between local host is: "joeys-macbook-pro.local/10.0.0.41"; destination host is: "localhost":9000; : java.io.EOFException; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EOFException
```

Comment: change `fs.default.name` to `hdfs://10.0.0.14:9000` or `hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000` maybe? `EOFException` on a socket might reflect that the connection was closed. Check if no other service is using that port.

Comment: change to `0.0.0.0` works thanks for your help.